# How to deny access to a method for a period of time?

Tags: java

I need to deny access to a function until a specific value is reached. For example, have the function sleep for values 5-10 on a variable and then perform it's action on 11, where the variable is manually incremented by 1 by the user. How can I set this up?

This is for a turn-based resource management game, running Java. I've tried setting the method to only run when a boolean value is true, and have it false when it should not be running.

Control switch statement

```
case "farm":
    if (farmAvailable = true) {
        farmAvailable = false;
        a.foodManagement(foodGenerator, food, storageBunker, day, 
                                 farmAvailable);
    } else if (farmAvailable = false) {
        System.out.println("Farming in progress...");
    }
    break;
```

Function being controlled

```
public int foodManagement(int generator, int currentStorage, int 
                             storageBunker, int day, boolean available) {
    int food = generator * 12;
    if (available == true) {
        int rest = day + 5;
        available = false;
        while (rest < day) {
            if (currentStorage + food > (storageBunker * 25)) {
                currentStorage += food;
                food = currentStorage - (storageBunker * 25); 
                System.out.println("Food storage full.");
                available = true;
                return food; 
            } else {
                available = true;
                return food;
            }
        }
    } else {
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This method should not run when farmAvailable is false, however nothing happens when you prompt the program to do so.

Comment: When you say 'deny access' do you mean the method can't be invoked or the method will return without doing anything?

Comment: `This is for a turn-based resource management game` Normally this is a function of the UI, not the method itself.  Your UI has a method that "disables" and greys out a button or other control, and doesn't re-enable until the timer pops.  The method itself is never disabled (there's really no way to do that from a code perspective).

Comment: @nicomp I mean the method will return without doing anything